# Swift: How to get the value of a slider in a custom cell in a dynamic UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uislider

I have a problem with the following scenario:

I have an `UITableView` with dynamic cells. Among others, I use a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UISlider`. How can I get the values of the sliders?

I created the following example: (The project file can be downloaded here: [Link](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11273737/SliderInCustomCell.zip.html))

SliderClass.swift

```
import UIKit

class SliderClass: NSObject {
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    var sliderMinimum: Float
    var sliderMaximum: Float

    init(title: String, subtitle: String, sliderMinimum: Float, sliderMaximum: Float) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.sliderMinimum = sliderMinimum
        self.sliderMaximum = sliderMaximum

    }
}
```

SliderTableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class SliderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellDetailTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellSlider: UISlider!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

TableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var slider: [SliderClass] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Slider"

        let slider1 = SliderClass(title: "Title1", subtitle: "Subtitle1", sliderMinimum: 0, sliderMaximum: 100)
        let slider2 = SliderClass(title: "Title2", subtitle: "Subtitle2", sliderMinimum: 0, sliderMaximum: 200)

        slider = [slider1, slider2]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return slider.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sliderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SliderTableViewCell

        let slider: SliderClass
        slider = self.slider[indexPath.row]

        cell.cellTextLabel.text = slider.title
        cell.cellDetailTextLabel?.text = slider.subtitle
        cell.cellSlider.minimumValue = slider.sliderMinimum
        cell.cellSlider.maximumValue = slider.sliderMaximum

        return cell
    }

    func sliderValueChange() {
     // I need help here:
     // Which slider changed to which value?

     // var slider = ...
     // var sliderValue = ...
     // NSLog("Value of slider:%@ changed to:%i", slider, sliderValue)
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the UITableView created with the code above.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding this to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
cell.cellSlider.tag = indexPath.row
cell.cellSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

And then outside of the table function add something like:

```
func sliderValueChange(sender: UISlider) {
    // Get the sliders value
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    var sliderRow = sender.tag

    // Do whatever you want with the value :)
    // And now the row of the slider!
}
```

Make sure the action name for `cellSlider`'s target is the same as the function's name! And since it takes one argument, don't forget the colon at the end.

So just to summarise, here's a really simply example of the above in action:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2    // 2 rows in the cell, for demo purposes
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.slider.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func sliderChange(sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = sender.value    // get slider's value
        let row = sender.tag               // get slider's row in table

        print("Slider in row \(row) has a value of \(currentValue)")
        // example output - Slider in row 1 has a value of 0.601399
    }

}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!

}
```

Comment: @Benjamin1956 Added a line in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to set the tag of the slider to the row which it's in. This is accessed by using `sender.tag` in the target function :)

Comment: @Benjamin1956 Also added a whole view controller file - kept it as simple as possible for you :)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this right away. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of a slider in a custom cell .

Hope this helps to you , Please go through the GitHub Code in Swift and refer screenshot

https://github.com/appcoda/expandable-table-view

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [ASValueTrackingSlider](https://github.com/alskipp/ASValueTrackingSlider). Note that is is written in `ObjectiveC`.